# Rhythmbox Android transfer error

Tags: android, rhythmbox, transfer

I want to transfer my music and playlists from Rhythmbox to my Android phone, a Samsung A3, more specifically to its SD card. I followed recommendations I found on several websites.

I created a Music folder on my SD card and pasted a mp3 file in it. I can see my phone in Rhythmbox but when I try to transfer music or synchronize the entire library, I get this message:

```
Erreur lors du transfert de la piste
Impossible d'ouvrir la ressource en écriture
```

Which can be roughly translated to:

```
Error while transferring the track
Impossible to write on the resource
```

It appears my phone is read-only for Rhythmbox, but I have no issue transferring files with Nautilus.

Comment: I have researched this for several days, I know your issue is frustrating but have you tested Clementine as your player.  For transfer to iPod device I switched. For my Android phone it transfers files from playlists to the SD card Music folder by drag and drop however the playlist itself does not.  I am currently looking for a way to do this, transferring playlist.m3u does not work with the default player on the phone.  Anyway, if I find a solution I'll post it as an option for you to consider.  I will test different players on the phone as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and fixed it by changing the USB transfer settings on my android phone.

1. Connect your phone to the computer, make sure to allow USB data transfer if your phone asks you
2. In your phone notifications list there should be an entry that says something like "USB for file transfer - tap for other USB options"
3. In the list of options that follows, choose the second option "Transfer images."

This is counter-intuitive, but once I changed the option the sync worked flawlessly. The phone icon in the devices menu has changed to a camera icon, but as long as the files transfer I'm happy.

This fix was performed on a Samsung Note 5 running Android 7.0, you can get more details of my original issue here: 
[Syncing music to Android with Rhythmbox "Error transferring track"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027607/syncing-music-to-android-with-rhythmbox-error-transferring-track)